# Your access has been denied by S3, please make sure your request credentials have permission to GetObject

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working cross account codepipeline
after creating changeset iam facing an issue
s3 bucket access denied  exception

[image]

please any body help

Comment: Can you show what policies the role has? seems like you are missing access policy for the bucket

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
S3BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref ArtifactS3Bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          -
            Action:
              - s3:*
            Effect: Allow
            Resource:
              - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${ArtifactS3Bucket}
              - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${ArtifactS3Bucket}/*
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${CodeCommitAccount}:role/CrossAccountCodeCommitRole
                - !GetAtt 'CodeBuildServiceRole.Arn'
                - !GetAtt 'CodePipelineServiceRole.Arn'
                - !GetAtt 'CloudFormationServiceRole.Arn'
```

Comment: this policy iam using